# Open Chrome from terminal with developer console open

Tags: shell, google-chrome, console, terminal, command-line-arguments

I can run Google Chrome from the command line using `$ google-chrome`, but what flag can I pass to open it with developer console already open, preferably open to the console tab?

I checked the man page for google-chrome but it states that

> Google Chrome has hundreds of undocumented command-line flags that are added and removed at the whim of the developers.

I'm hoping one of those undocumented flags does what I want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The flag you're looking for is [--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#auto-open-devtools-for-tabs). Please note, that you should **quit Chrome** before this setting will take effect.

This has worked at least since Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (the latest version as of initial post)

Comment: uh no it doesn't work, it starts chrome normally without the dev tools open.

Comment: @kuhaku this worked for everybody I spoke with so far. Are you sure you're spinning up chrome correctly?

Comment: It does work. You just need to flag '--args' and then '--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs'. Also make sure you quit Chrome before running the command.

Comment: This argument will open devtools on every new tab, not just the requested page, and you need to exit Chrome before running the command.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but I didn't close Chrome beforehand.

Comment: @toad not sure what you mean here. Isn't working for me. I'm using nodejs npm `open` to launch chrome with `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` as an argument and no joy...

Answer (score 9):

A Google employee maintains this list of automatically updated [Chromium flags](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). There doesn't seem to be a flag for opening Chrome with developer console open.

Comment: You should change your accepted answer to [@Dethariel's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41452619/4194289) it works on newer versions of chrome.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve by that? If you are trying to run some kind of automated tests, you should try out PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no such option. I added a feature request in Chrome product forum
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/give-feature-feedback-and-suggestions/mac/Stable/3HYIAl8_ndc