# Chrome's --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to get the devtools to open automatically when starting chrome from a shortcut with a command line switch `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`.

i.e. the path of that shortcut is: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito -auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` (or --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs).

But both don't seem to open the dev tools, neither does entering in the cmd `chrome.exe -auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` (or --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs), of course when in Chrome's folder.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

The command is from:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#auto-open-devtools-for-tabs

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41452619/4279201

Comment: Hmm, works in Chrome 58+ (with two dashes, of course). Make sure you've fully exited the browser e.g. via Quit command or by killing all chrome processes.

Comment: I have another window open, for this to work only one window of chrome can be opened? The `-ingocnito` works fine with another window open. @wOxxOm

Comment: Evidently, this is a global switch, not a per-session one.

Answer (score 12):

This flag only applies when you open the first chrome instance.

1. Close all chrome windows
2. Run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito -auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

If you want your daily browser, with all tabs but without devtools, at the same time as you're debugging a website with devtools automatically opening, you have to run them separately.

**Alternative: Stable + Beta**

One example is to use example Chrome stable and Chrome beta.

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe" --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

**Alternative: data-dir**

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --user-data-dir="%APPDATA%\ChromeDevOrAnyName"`

Comment: You don't need a separate version of Chrome browser, you could simply use `--user-data-dir` flag.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that I need to quit all Chrome instances first.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev thanks, I've added that as an alternative.

Comment: thank you, I got it, it worked when i 'Endtask' Google Chorme first,

Comment: looks like default path for chrome has changed to `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`