# Open devTools on chrome on "Console" tab in cypress (docker)

Tags: docker, google-chrome-devtools, cypress, chromium

I would like to automatically open devTools on browser start.

I have already found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909743/chromes-auto-open-devtools-for-tabs) and it works, but by default devTools are opened on "Elements".

I need it to somehow open on "Console" tab. either by setting default tab or removing other tabs.

It is for cypress tests that are launched inside of docker container using "cypress/browsers" image with "cypress@6.8.0" installed inside.

Why I need this?
I have some specific issue that is showing only when testing with cypress that is running inside docker container (couldn't reproduce it on other environments)

Tried to find something on this [site](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but nothing seems to do what I need.

Comment: If Chrome doesn´t provide for you, you might send the hotkey via the open source autoitscript.com whenever a certain pixel is not eah console-colored.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagyi If I'm not mistaken autoIt is for windows. My cypress is running on docker container which uses linux.

Comment: @mindparse unfortunately no. I have used a workaround for my specific case.